# Spring kafka Consumer Not Working When deployed in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I  have a spring kafka consumer that reads  messages from a topic and writes to another topic . I am using spring kafka 2.1.8. When this application is running as spring boot it works fine.When deployed as a war to an external tomcat server (tried pivotal tc server on my workstation as well as an external tomcat server),consumer reads one message ,send to  downstream topic and is stuck. All that I can see is the heart beat message send to the co ordinator. Exact same code process 100's of messages when run as spring boot. I am not sure if this has something to do with spring kafka or my ignorance with spring boot.

```
@Bean
      public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> consumerProperties = new HashMap<>();
        consumerProperties.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaConfigService.getKAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS());
        consumerProperties.put("client.id", "rawlogs_client");
        consumerProperties.put("group.id", "rawlogs_etl");
        consumerProperties.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
        consumerProperties.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        consumerProperties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        consumerProperties.put("value.deserializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer");
        consumerProperties.put("schema.registry.url", kafkaConfigService.getKAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL());
        consumerProperties.put("isolation.level", "read_committed");
        consumerProperties.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);
        consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        consumerProperties.put("max.poll.records", "100");
        return consumerProperties;
      }
         @Bean
      public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
          ConsumerFactory<String, SpecificRecord> kafkaConsumerFactory
         ) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SpecificRecord> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(kafkaTransactionManager());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.BATCH);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleEventInterval(60000L);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
        factory.setRetryTemplate(getRetryTemplate());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerTaskExecutor(threadPoolExecutor());
        return factory;
      }



               @Bean
              public RetryTemplate getRetryTemplate() {
                  RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
                  FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
                  backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(1000);
                  RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
                  retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
                  retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
                  retryTemplate.registerListener(retryListener());
                  return retryTemplate;
              }
    @Bean
     public  ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolExecutor() {
             ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor= new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
             executor.setMaxPoolSize(3);
             executor.initialize();
             return executor;
         }
```

Comment: I think that Tomcat doesn't like an internal `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` in the `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`. Consider to create an appropriate bean for the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and inject it into the `ContainerProperties`.

Comment: Thanks Artem,I tried that but  got the same result .I am adding the container factory config above. Ran in debug mode and that doesn't help either

Comment: Huh? I don't see there any executor injections.

Comment: My bad .Just pasted the latest configuration

Comment: Why it’s not a `@Bean` ?

Comment: Sorry about that ,still coming to terms with spring. It was defined as bean but I did not paste it .Edited the question with correct configuration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179658/discussion-between-nishanth-shajahan-and-artem-bilan).