# Is it possible to use a Kafka client in a Spring Boot application deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, apache-kafka

We are trying to add a Kafka client in a Spring Boot application working with a Kinesis client.
This app is deployed as a war file on AWS Elastic Beanstalk apache Tomcat server.
We are getting the following error:

```
2021-05-26 10:16:28.406  INFO [Events hub producer,,,] 18707 --- [-kinesis-consumer-1] 
a.i.k.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : Got an exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Connection pool shut down during 
[ShardConsumer{shardOffset=KinesisShardOffset{iteratorType=AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER, 
sequenceNumber='49597500435060696094196305874047828104515719714507325442', timestamp=null, 
stream='eventshubdmpdev', shard='shardId-000000000000', reset=false}, state=CONSUME}] task 
invocation.
```

So my question is:

1. Is it possible?
2. Has someone experience doing this?
3. Are there any
   known issues?

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming networking is configured correctly, yes, it's possible. Removing Kafka tag because this is a kinesis error

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, yes, the problem seems to be a Tomcat related problem, here is the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52227327/spring-kafka-consumer-not-working-when-deployed-in-tomcat

Comment: That question provided no logs, and doesn't say anything about kinesis (the error you've shown here isn't about Kafka), so like I said, assuming networking is good, everything should work... Personally, I have deployed spring-boot apps into various container environments on AWS and they work fine with Kafka

Comment: Using both? I mean, having one Spring Boot app consuming from AWS Kinesis and Kafka? Could you please provide your properties configuration, or a part of them?

Comment: We don't use kinesis, only Kafka. Properties don't look any different than regular spring-kafka properties. There used to be other teams that used Kafka Connect or Spring Reactor project to migrate Kinesis data into Kafka, but since then, I think it's all Kafka

Comment: Well that's the point of the question and it's quite clear in the problem description: "We are trying to add a Kafka client in a Spring Boot application working with a Kinesis client".

Comment: And my answer is that adding an extra dependency (for anything) shouldn't cause kinesis errors on its own, regardless of where it's deployed. If you want to be more specific about what has changed in your code, [edit] your question to include a [mcve]